# Can I add my partner's email address to view my Admob account?

Tags: admob

Is there any way for others to view estimated earning or other details by using their own email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. An account is linked to a single email address.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update that the New Admob does allow others to check account statements!